# LWC Button Icon Name is not displayed sometime during page load:

Tags: lightning-web-components, button, refresh, cookies

I have created below LWC Button with icon-name.

```
<template>
        <div class="slds slds-p-around--medium">
            <lightning-card class="slds-theme_shade wrapper" variant="base" title={label.CriteriaSection}
                icon-name="standard:topic">
                <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="ABC__c" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label={label.SearchBtn} title={label.SearchButton}
                        onclick={handleSearchClk} icon-name="utility:search" class="slds-m-left_x-small">
                    </lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button variant="destructive" label={label.ResetBtn} title={label.ResetButton}
                        onclick={handleResetClk} icon-name="utility:reset_password" class="slds-m-left_x-small">
                    </lightning-button>
                </lightning-record-edit-form>
                
            </lightning-card>
            </div>
</template>
```

During page load sometimes the icon-name loads. If it does not load then I have to refresh the page again and again till  icon-name is loaded. It loads label name correctly.

When it does not load, I have observed below warning message to the chrome browser console. **I am on chrome version 84.**

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at
> http://salesforce.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It
> has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site
> requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can
> review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies
> and see more details at
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

also there is an issue tab where below error message is displayed:

> Because a cookie's SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it
> defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in
> a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from
> accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.
>
> Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
>
> Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in
> cross-site requests. This enables third-party use. Specify
> SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent in
> cross-site requests

in affected resource it shows icon name which is failed to load.

Can someone please help?

Comment: can you show js also?

Comment: @salesforce-sas there is no logic written in JS. just imported Label using import labelName from '@salesforce/label/label-reference';

Comment: @salesforce-sas this behavior is observed at any time. Its not necessary that it does not display button icon during first time of page load. Its kind of unpredictable but warning messages which is mentioned do come when button icon failed to load.

Comment: I think this is [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001SqocQAC) already reported to salesforce.

Comment: @rahulgawale thanks for the link. is there any way where I can load icons within button?
does static resource work work?

Comment: Although I experienced this, it happens rarely for me and thought it was internet issue and reloaded. @rahulgawale.. you should probably make it answer

Comment: @DhananjayPatil its not a prob, google will release fix very soon

Comment: @DhananjayPatil If you change the view to `Comfy`, then it solves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001SqocQAC) and already reported to Salesforce and Chromium. I hope it will be resolved very soon. Already 122 people including me have reported it, you can also do so.

> In Chrome version 84, some icons, such as Help [question icon], Setup
> [gear icon]), are not appearing.
>
> The problem was introduced with the Chrome version 84 and has been
> reported to the Chromium project, and can be tracked at the URL:
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1107442. While
> this issue is not exclusive to Salesforce, we are monitoring closely
> as we understand this has a high impact on our users.

Comment: Hi @Rahul Display Density is already set to Comfy in my application but still it does not display the buttons sometime.I have also observed that, it does not load standard setup,notifications and help icon along with my custom button.It looks like this is impacted to Standard Button icon too.

Comment: yes, standard icons too affected by this. Setting density to comfy worked for me. looks like it does not work for all orgs.